# "Specify type explicitly" checked by default in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA IDE offers "Introduce variable" refactoring feature for Kotlin language. Popup shown by the variable being introduced allow to "Specify type explicitly" (switchable by <kbd>Alt + T</kbd>).

How to make "Specify type explicitly" option selected by default?

[image: Idea "Introduce variable popup screenshot]

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: There is a feature request for Kotlin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11883

Comment: Yes, I was asking about Kotlin, added to the question.

Comment: @PetrRastegaev feel free to add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. IMO "Not yet possible" is also an answer.